# Fail deploying socket io ws server on heroku Nodejs PHP project

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, websocket, socket.io

I would create a **ws** server for a chat that I have already built but it's not working. I spent hours looking for a way to solve my problem but nothing. Heroku having not any reel support. I'm asking for help here.
So node **js ws** server and php backend.

Here the architecture:

[image]

My server code here:

```
'use strict';
 
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const INDEX = '/index2.php';
 
const server = express()
  .use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX, { root: __dirname }))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));
 
const io = socketIO(server);
 
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Client connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
});
 
setInterval(() => io.emit('time', new Date().toTimeString()), 1000);
```

Here my client part about socket:

```
        var socket = io("https://xamchat.herokuapp.com/", {withCredentials: true});

       

        if (socket.connected) {
            alert("connected")
            socket.emit("connection")
            socket.on('time', function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        });
        } else {
            alert("not connected")
        }
```

and I get this error in **js** console:

> polling-xhr.js:157 GET
> https://herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NooXUGB 404
> (Not Found)

I have also tried to make an express server, same error...

Comment: Did you try it on local environment? Is it working?

Comment: Yes it worked....

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const INDEX = '/index2.php';

app.use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX, { root: __dirname }))

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Client connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
});

http.listen(PORT, function() {
   console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`);
   setInterval(() => io.emit('time', new Date().toTimeString()), 1000);
});
```

Comment: I have just test it. Still doesn't work. If you want you can test on the link: https://xamchat.herokuapp.com/index2.php    pseudo:guest_1 pass:guest_1

Comment: do you have a github links or something like that?

Comment: It is hosted on heroku but there's the google drive link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TbEDdg4Pc__JonDyv_VeanpYdEqzLkXS?usp=sharing